# How to implement both the Admin & Customer Panel in Laravel

Tags: laravel

**NewBee

**Laravel

I want to access the admin panel using the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin` and the customer panel using the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

`Customer Login: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login`

`Admin Login: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/`

I have set a session variable to identify whether the user is `admin or customer` in my `AdminController.php` and checking on each function that this user must be an admin to access. Below is the script

### AdminController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use Session;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return view('admin.index');
    }

    public function login(Request $request) {
            
        Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password, 'user_type' => 'admin']);

        //was any of those correct ?
        if ( Auth::check() ) {
            //send them where they are going 
            Session::put('userType', 'admin');
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }

        return redirect('/admin')->with('flash_message', 'Invalid Credentials');
    }

    public function dashboard() {
        if( Session::has('userType') and Session::get('userType') == 'admin' )
            return view('admin.dashboard');
        else
            return redirect('/admin')->with('flash_message', 'Please login to access');
    }

    public function posts() {
        if( Session::has('userType') and Session::get('userType') == 'admin' )
            return view('admin.posts');
        else
            return redirect('/admin')->with('flash_message', 'Please login to access');
    }

    public function logout() {
        Session::flush();
        return redirect()->route('admin');
    }
}
```

I am checking if the user is admin in every function like this `if( Session::has('userType') and Session::get('userType') == 'admin' )`. So is there any way to do it in a better way??????

Now when I logged into the admin panel then I can access the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home` for customer as well, but this should not be accessed because I have logged in as an admin not as a customer.

Now how can I enable session variable for 2 different types of users and ensure the accessibility of the users???

### web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
Route::post('/admin/login', 'AdminController@login')->name('admin.login');
Route::get('/admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard')->name('admin.dashboard');
Route::get('/admin/posts', 'AdminController@posts')->name('admin.posts');
Route::get('/admin/logout', 'AdminController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
```

Comment: I think you should go through some tutorials on how to develop role based auth, i.e using guards or middleware etc. You'll find better options.

Comment: I agree with Gaurav Rai - go through some tutorials.  Also, you need to look into middleware so you can make your Controllers a lot thinner.  You should apply middleware to your admin only routes and check the correct role there in stead of adding that same logic on all your controller methods.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information, I will definitely have a look and try to implement it.

Comment: Hey, I have done this, can you please tell me how can I set a session just after log in using Laravel's default auth??

Answer (score 0):

What you need is either [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware) or some kind of third party packages like [laratrsut](https://laratrust.santigarcor.me/docs/5.0/)